# AutoIt- How to enter a value in textbox on Bitvise

Tags: autoit

I want to write for a program to connect SSH using Bitvise SSH Client.

How can I enter a value in textbox (Host, usename and pass) in Bitvise SSH client?

I tried using `ControlSetText` but it didn't work.
Please help me!

[image: Jz5Lv]

[image: B2o3e]

Comment: What is use case here ? why you want to connect to env using Bitvise SSH client only in your automation. you can use java and Jsch lib to connect to a unix env.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ControlSend` or `Send` to send raw key strokes. ControlSend is more reliable so I would try that first.

Use the Control tab on the AutoIt Window Info Tool to get the control for that window then use that with ControlSend.